# iOS equivalent of Androids ValueAnimator

Tags: ios, animation

I would like something that mimics the behaviour in iOS of the `ValueAnimator` in Android. Under normal circumstances I would use a `UIView` animation, but unfortunately the objects value im trying to interpolate over time isnt working with a normal animation.

In my particular case im using a `Lottie` animation, and trying to change the progress of the animation via a `UIView` animation, but instead of the animation changing the value of the progress over time, it just jumps to the final value. eg:

```
let lottieAnim = ...
lottieAnim.animationProgress = 0

UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) {
    lottieAnim.animationProgress = 1
}
```

This example does not animate the lottie animation over time, but simply jumps to the end. I know lottie has methods to play the animation, but Im trying to use a custom animation curve to set the progress (its a progress animation that has no finite duration) which is why I need to use a `UIView` animation to interpolate the value.

I need something that updates intermittently to mimic an animation, the first thing that comes to mind is Android `ValueAnimator` class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I put together a class that will mimic a `ValueAnimator` from android somewhat, and will allow you to specify your own animation curve if need be (default is just linear)

*Simple usage*

```
let valueAnimator = ValueAnimator(duration: 2) { value in
  animationView.animationProgress = value
}

valueAnimator.start()
```

*Advanced usage*

```
let valueAnimator = ValueAnimator(from: 0, to: 100, duration: 60, animationCurveFunction: { time, duration in
  return atan(time)*2/Double.pi
}, valueUpdater: { value in
  animationView.animationProgress = value
})

valueAnimator.start()
```

You can cancel it at any point as well using:

```
valueAnimator.cancel()
```

Value Animator class in Swift 5

```
// swiftlint:disable:next private_over_fileprivate
fileprivate var defaultFunction: (TimeInterval, TimeInterval) -> (Double) = { time, duration in
  return time / duration
}

class ValueAnimator {

  let from: Double
  let to: Double
  var duration: TimeInterval = 0
  var startTime: Date!
  var displayLink: CADisplayLink?
  var animationCurveFunction: (TimeInterval, TimeInterval) -> (Double)
  var valueUpdater: (Double) -> Void

  init (from: Double = 0, to: Double = 1, duration: TimeInterval, animationCurveFunction: @escaping (TimeInterval, TimeInterval) -> (Double) = defaultFunction, valueUpdater: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
    self.from = from
    self.to = to
    self.duration = duration
    self.animationCurveFunction = animationCurveFunction
    self.valueUpdater = valueUpdater
  }

  func start() {
    displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(update))
    displayLink?.add(to: .current, forMode: .default)
  }

  @objc
  private func update() {

    if startTime == nil {
      startTime = Date()
      valueUpdater(from + (to - from) * animationCurveFunction(0, duration))
      return
    }

    var timeElapsed = Date().timeIntervalSince(startTime)
    var stop = false

    if timeElapsed > duration {
      timeElapsed = duration
      stop = true
    }

    valueUpdater(from + (to - from) * animationCurveFunction(timeElapsed, duration))

    if stop {
      cancel()
    }
  }

  func cancel() {
    self.displayLink?.remove(from: .current, forMode: .default)
    self.displayLink = nil
  }
}
```

You could probably improve this to be more generic but this serves my purpose.

Comment: Would you know how to add repeatCount. Android can also repeat animations and has value of ValueAnimator.INFINITE

Comment: @tech_human in where we set `stop = true`, you could instead just have a counter that sets it to true after a certain amount of times, and all you need to do is just reset the `startTime` back to `nil` so it restarts from the beginning, should work i think

Comment: For me, stop = true was never getting executed since algorithm returns from if check of startTime == nil. I had to remove return and update some logic there for my case. I wanted to add reverse - repeat i.e. reversing from and to and also adding a repeat count. Your algo is a good starting point for me. Thanks for sharing!